# How to perform ssl-verification with python-requests?

Tags: python

My company creates a certificate for each user, a certificate that is loaded into my browser.
It contains the name and e-mail address of the authorized user and is automatically checked by the server on each reconnect to verify the user's identity, potentially without even entering a password.

Now I need to use python to send https request to my company's site. How to do? I read the **requests** documents and found `requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/server.crt', '/path/key'))`. Should I import the certificate from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/ - you just set 'verify=True' in the request.

requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=True)

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'kennethreitz.com' doesn't match either of '*.herokuapp.com', 'herokuapp.com'